# how to set a default window manager

Tags: 12.04, compiz

UBuntu 12.04 LTS uses Compiz 0.9.7.12 as a default window manager. Where UBuntu stores an information which window manager is used by default ? I want to permanently switch to the metacity or run compiz with parameters, for example compiz --debug core composite opengl.

Comment: I installed **mdm** as default display manager for Ubuntu 12.04. I replaced **lightdm** with **mdm** and I am satisfied with the results. Login greeter is nicer and can be customized, and there are a lot of other features, including security features that you can customize with the 'Login Window' app which comes together with MDM.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu stores the information in

```
/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/"YOURSESSION"
```

The property `DefaultProvider-windowmanager` is where you set your default window manager.

Like this `DefaultProvider-windowmanager=metacity`