# How do I get appearances back to the normal after installing Gnome?

Tags: unity, gnome, window-manager

I installed Gnome as an alternative desktop environment on 14.04. However, since rebooting:

- the loader graphic when starting and shutting down my machien shows the Gnome foot rather than the Ubuntu logo
- my login screen looks slightly different
- when I log into my Ubuntu (Unity) desktop environment, the window decorations are distinctly different.

How do I restore the appearance of my Ubuntu (Unity) loader, login screen and desktop to the default settings?

---

While it was installing an dialog came up asking me which window manager should be my default. I thought the answer was "lightdm" so I picked that. I have since found out [that is probably not the cause](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58528/whats-the-difference-between-gdm-and-lightdm).

Based on the answer to [How to set a default window manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436884/how-to-set-a-default-window-manager) I tried looking at `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu.session` but it doesn't contain a `DefaultProvider-windowmanager` property.

If I run `sudo update-alternatives --config x-window-manager` I get:

```
There is only one alternative in link group x-window-manager (providing /usr/bin/x-window-manager): /usr/bin/mutter
Nothing to configure.
```

Comment: is something like `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` useful?

Comment: @arsaKasra that is the dialog I got before - the choices are gdm and lightdm - based on other questions, I assume lightdm is in fact the correct choice?

Comment: I have not tried that, but perhaps since you are going to have Gnome as your desktop then gdm is not too irrelevant of an option. There's only the two of them, not too many to try.

Answer (score 3):

For the loader graphic: type

> sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth

in Terminal window. Choose ubuntu-logo.plymouth.
For the login screen - try

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm ubuntu-desktop

For Unity - open open Appereance and change theme.