# Is Mutter supposed to be my window manager on plain Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, gnome, 14.04, window-manager, mutter

I [ran into some problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455118/how-do-i-get-appearances-back-to-the-normal-after-installing-gnome) after installing Gnome on my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop. I have managed to address most appearance-related issues.

However, if I run `sudo update-alternatives --config x-window-manager` I get:

```
There is only one alternative in link group x-window-manager (providing /usr/bin/x-window-manager): /usr/bin/mutter
Nothing to configure.
```

[As far as I know,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutter_%28software%29) Mutter is the window manager for Gnome, not Unity. What is the window manager for Unity and how can I install/restore it? (Alternatively, does Unity 7 / 14.04 in fact use Mutter?)

Answer (score 1):

No, it must be lightdm.
Restore it by using:

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

or

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm

Comment: am I correct that lightdm is the default?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: I did that, selected lightdm and restarted, there is no visible difference and the update-alternatives command returns the same result - any suggestions? based on what I've read, is it possible lightdm is only for the login screen and not a window manager? should compiz be the window manager, or is that only for older versions?

Comment: It can be Compiz or Metacity.