# Getting Unity style back after installing Gnome

Tags: unity, gnome

I really like GNOME's shortcuts, so I installed it. It didn't only change the shortcuts, but all the icons and error sounds and everything. Even the way files are displayed running ls in terminal changed.

Switching back to Unity doesn't

How can I bring back Unity (with the icons and styles)?

My question could be a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455118/how-do-i-get-appearances-back-to-the-normal-after-installing-gnome) it didn't get any fulfilling answer, so I guess I could ask again.

Comment: Have you tried to set the theme back to Ambiance or Radiance in Appearance in System Settings?

Comment: @nastys yes, and that partially solved the problem. Some icons are still different, and pop up dialogs aren't the same - but it's a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Tweak Tool:
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool/

then open it and go to Appearance and set the icons to Ubuntu-mono-dark (Ambiance) or Ubuntu-mono-light (Radiance).

[image]

Comment: This doesn't bring the whole feel of Unity back, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't uninstall unity, just log out, choose unity session from the login screen and it should be there. If you did uninstall unity, just do `sudo apt-get install unity*` then it should install it for you. To be honest you if you like the unity icons, you can just go to the theme settings and change it to the unity ones. I think they're either called ambiance or radiance.